# Angular: prevent default not working when clicking on div

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/uKZaCCcWfrQMdoXeNRd9?p=preview) I have two divs. The first div (orange color) contains the second div (blue color). The objective is to show an alert when you click on a div.

If you click on the orange div (directive dir1), you'll see the alert. But if you click on the blue div (directive dir2), you will see **two** alerts, because prevent default `e.preventDefault()` is not stopping the chain of events. How to make this work?

HTML:

```
  <div dir1 style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:orange">
       <div dir2 style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:blue"> </div>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
app.directive('dir1', function() {

    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'EA';

    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {

        element.bind('click', function() {
            alert('clicked on dir1');
        });
    }

    return directive;

});



app.directive('dir2', function() {

    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'EA';

    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {

        element.bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('clicked on dir2');
        });
    }

   return directive;

});
```

Comment: You want `stopPropagation()`, not `preventDefault()`. `preventDefault` is used to stop things like links navigating away from the page, form submissions, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use e.stopPropogation() to stop the event from propogating

```
element.bind('click', function(e) {
               e.stopPropagation();
              alert('clicked on dir2');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `e.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 0):

yeah, use e.stopProgation() but remember that if you need to re-render the view after your element is clicked you will need to use $apply for example:

```
  element.on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    // In order to work with stopPropagation and two data way binding
    // if you don't use scope.$apply in my case the model is not updated in the view when I click on the element that has my directive
    scope.$apply(function () {
      scope.myModel.updateAttributeStatus = true;
    });
  });
```